# I can not understand this code

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof

I had to remove same data in array. 
I found this code and its work exactly the way i want but I can not understand part of this code.
please explain this code and WHAT IS THIS >>>  **a[this[i]]**   <<<

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    var a = {}; //new Object
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (typeof a[this[i]] == 'undefined') {
            a[this[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    this.length = 0; //clear the array
    for (var i in a) {
        this[this.length] = i;
    }
    return this;
  };
```

Comment: That code is dated and not very reliable. (It will remove `'toString'`, `'hasOwnProperty'`, etc. when used on an array of strings, will convert any other type to strings, and is permitted by the language specification to produce results out of order.) Use `Array.from(new Set(array))` to get an array without duplicates.

Comment: `i` is a number, `this[i]` is an element of this array, `a[this[i]]` is a property in `var a`

Comment: @Ry - how would that work with Internet Exploder :p - also, that would not change the array "in place" - perhaps that's important too

Comment: @Ry, it would not remove those methods at all ... not sure why you think it would

Comment: @JaromandaX: Did you try it? `['toString', 'hasOwnProperty', 'foo'].unique()`

Comment: `this` is self reference to the array; `i` is the arrays numeric key; typeof checks the variable type;  the `for` loop here is simply populating any undefined (empty) array elements (kinda messy tho).  this is real basic stuff.

Comment: @Ry - I misunderstood where you were coming from! Yes, that makes perfect sense! (easily fixed though)

Comment: Another option would be to use `.filter`, like `[1,1,2,2,3,4,'a','b','b',null,null].filter((item, index, array) => array.indexOf(item) === index) // → [1,2,3,4,'a','b',null]`. But i suspect using `Set` as @Ry suggested might be more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the comments before each line that explain that line of code
//added unique function to prototype of array so that all array can have unique //function access

```
    Array.prototype.unique = function() {
        //creating a temp object which will hold array values as keys and 
         //value as "1"  to mark that key exists
        var a = {}; //new Object
        //this points to the array on which you have called unique function so
        //if arr = [1,2,3,4] and you call arr.unique() "this" will point to 
        //arr in below code iterating over each item in array
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        //idea is to take the value from array and add that as key in a so 
        //that next time it is defined. this[i] points to the array item at 
        //that index(value of i) //and a[this[i]] is adding a property on a 
        //with name "this[i]" which is the value //at that index  so if value 
        //at that index is lets say 2 then a[this[i]] is //referring to 
        //a["2"].thus if 2 exists again at next index you do not add it to a
        //again as it is defined
            if (typeof a[this[i]] == 'undefined') {
                a[this[i]] = 1;
            }
        }
        this.length = 0; //clear the array
        //now in a the properties are unique array items you are just looping 
        //over those props and adding it into current array(this) in which 
        //length will increase every //time you put a value 
        for (var i in a) {
            this[this.length] = i;
        }
        //at the end returning this which is the modified array
        return this;
      };
```

//Edit

stored value of a[this[i]] is 1 for all the keys in a it will be one.
you start with

```
arr = [1,2,3,2,3,4];
```

when you call arr.unique
the code in the first loop creates a something like this

```
a = {
"1":1,
"2":1,
"3":1,
"4":1
}
```

so you can see that only unique values are as properties in a.
Now in the for-in loop you are just taking the keys of a(ie 1,2,3,4) and adding it to the array(this).

Hope this helps let me know if you need more details

Comment: note: `if (typeof a[this[i]] == 'undefined') {` is redundant ... just `a[this[i]] = 1;` will do

Comment: thx its helped a lot but i still confuse `a[this[i]] =1;` how its store value not '1'.   i think all values of `a[]` have to be '1'

Comment: @JHYOO: I don’t know if you saw the edit to this answer yet, but it explains that. Yes, every value of `a` is `1`, but it’s the keys that matter.

Comment: @Ry︁: I saw the edited answer. now i totally understand about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

`a[this[i]]` =>
`this[i]` -> get `i` element from current object, in this case it's Array.
`a[]` -> get element from `var a` at position specified in `[]`, in this case what value is inside `this[i]`